# UnitTest (groovy + grails) - Cannot teardown metaclass

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails, groovy, metaclass

I'm having a problem when I try to clean the class.

```
void testFileExists() {

  FileObject file = EasyMock.createMock(FileObject.class)

  VfsFileSystemManager.metaClass.getFile = {String s, String a ->return file}

  FileObject.metaClass.exists = {-> return true}

  assertEquals true, siteManagerHelper.fileExists(STRING, STRING)

}

void testFileNotExists() {

  FileObject file = EasyMock.createMock(FileObject.class)

  VfsFileSystemManager.metaClass.getFile = {String s, String a ->return file}

  FileObject.metaClass.exists = {-> return false}

  assertEquals false, siteManagerHelper.fileExists(STRING, STRING)

}
```

When I run one at the time, they work fine, but if I run both at the same time, exists() always return true (if I change the first .metaclass for false, it returns false). So I assume it's not tearing down the metaclass.

The class extends GroovyTestCase, and I checked that I should add:

```
def remove = GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.&removeMetaClass
remove FileObject
```

But it's not working.

Please, help!

EDIT:

I'm using grails 1.3.7 and groovy 1.6.8

```
private boolean fileExists(String path, String file){

    if(path != null && path != ""){

     FileObject fileToCheck = fsManager.getFile(path, file)

     boolean fileExists = fileToCheck.exists()

     logger.debug "File exists? ${fileExists}"

     return fileExists
    }

    logger.debug "The path is null or empty"

    return false

}
```

Comment: Can you show the fileExists() method? Are you using Grails 2.x?

Comment: Have you tried just setting the FileObject's meta class to null in your tear down method instead of going through the metaclass registry? Setting it to null should reset it to its default behavior, and then each test should properly override it.

Comment: I just tried, but it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue (Grails 2.2.0) and I was able to surmount it by following the below:

1. Use `GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.removeMetaClass(FileObject.class)` in the end of the test method to tear down
2. Use `FileObject.metaClass = null` in test class tearDown()

I still wonder why do we need to use both tearDown simultaneously.

Note:- In my case I metaClassed a Groovy Object as compared to a Java Object.